# Salesforce Aura (Lightning Component) Uncaught Error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

**Getting the below error on aura lightning component. Not getting this error on the developer org (where I am building this managed package application), but getting this in organizations where I am installing this managed package.**

[image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding try/catch around the callback function solved the issue for now.